# Common criteria restriction in Hibernate for all queries for all tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have already finished writing a lot of queries in hibernate for my project. Now my requirement has changed and a new column name ACTIVE is added in all the tables I have in MySql. I have no permission to deny the addition of ACTIVE column. The ACTIVE field can hold values true or false and I have to add that to the criteria too. So, I have been thinking is there a way I could add a criteria restriction in Hibernate that is kind of common to all the queries I make, instead of putting that criteria for every query I make?

EDIT: Little misunderstanding I suppose, sorry for that, I was in hurry while typing this.
The ACTIVE column will be already set to true or false by some other user. What I need to is a global filtering only for the records having ACTIVE column as true for every query I fire.

Something like this but I want hibernate to add the the ACTIVE='true' filter for every query I fire,

```
select name from table where <other-conditions-here> and ACTIVE='true'
```

Hope that make sense.

Thanks and regards,

Sunayan Saikia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hibernate filters for this purpose. for details refer [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would advice you to implement a custom interceptor, Which should intercept your queries and append `ACTIVE` criteria before they are executed.

Interceptor details could be found here: [**Hibernate Interceptors**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/events.html)