# HQL that returns nested children where all the children matches the condition

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, hql, criteria

I have a class Parent with a one-to-many children set. The children is nested and can have n number as depth. I want to write a hql which will return a parent with children, grandchildren, great-grandchildren etc that matches a condition. 
I was able to get children that matches the condition, but when i call, children.getChildren, it returns grand children which do not matches the condition. Is this possibile?

Thanks,
Parvathy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

1. When you fetch Parent class' object, lazily load its child objects by specifying `lazy = false` either in the mapping file or at Entity level. As far as you condition is concerned, you can write the logic in your programming language (e.g. loop over the child objects).
2. Write a recursive logic, that makes database hit till the last nth grandchild is fetched. It cannot be accomplished with single criteria or HQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the answer I was looking for. Do you think adding a @Filter to the one-to-many getchildren() would also help?

Comment: See this for filters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448524/common-criteria-restriction-in-hibernate-for-all-queries-for-all-tables/13449011#13449011

Comment: @ParvathyMohan if you found filter suggestion helpful ,please mark it as answer .

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can ,But  you have add restrictions on them also .

```
     criteria = session.createCriteria(YourClass.class);
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eq
                ("yourClassproperty", value));// //condition on parent
                criteria.createAlias("children", "child");
                criteria.createAlias("child.grandeChild", "grandChild");
                criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq
                ("child.prop", value), Restrictions.
                eq("grandChild.property", value)));
                //Exmple restrictions on children
                criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
                return criteria.list();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but my problem is the depth of the children can be n

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but my problem is the depth of the children can be n. there can be children for grandchildren and so on.

Comment: Sounds like not possible with the criteria .We can apply a for loop but atlease we have to know where the loop ends .